# Add Properties to Lit React Wrapper (using @lit/react)

Tags: reactjs, web-component, lit

Ok, there's a lit web component I need to use in a React app (which is using TS/TSX).
(In case you think the naming here is odd, I'm using dummy names)

I know I can just have the web component in React like this:

```html
<lit-web-component text="my text"></lit-web-component>
```

And that works, it displays the component.
However, this lit component also dispatches an event, and I need the React app to catch this.
After researching, I found that I need to use a package(@lit/react) and create a wrapper component to do this. (https://lit.dev/docs/frameworks/react/)

I'm following the documentation, but I keep getting an error with the properties on the lit component (text). It gives this error:

```
Type '{ text: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, never> & EventListeners<{}> & Partial<Omit<HTMLElement, keyof HTMLElement>> & RefAttributes<...>'.
  Property 'text' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, never> & EventListeners<{}> & Partial<Omit<HTMLElement, keyof HTMLElement>> & RefAttributes<...>
```

Here is the React wrapper component I'm creating:

```
export const MyElementComponent = createComponent({
  tagName: 'lit-web-component',
  elementClass: LitWebComponent,
  react: React,
  events: {
    onHeaderButtonClick: 'header-button-click',
  },
});
```

And then using it in react as: `<MyElementComponent text="my text" />`

And it produces the above error. I have no idea how to tell it that this wrapper needs to take in these properties.

`LitWebComponent` is being imported as `import { LitWebComponent } from '@my-scope/my-lit-library';`

How do I declare these properties?

I hope that this issue is solvable on the React side, making changes to the lit component would be difficult.

Comment: I have faced a similar issue when using a web component without a React wrapper in a React project. Are you sure you are using a wrapper component in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I'll start off by saying you might not need to use `@lit/react` for your use case if it's giving you trouble, and props you need to pass in are just strings.

You can use a ref to imperatively add event listeners.

```
const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const handler = (e) => { /* do stuff */ }
      ref.current.addEventListener('header-button-click', handler);
      return () => {
        ref.current.removeEventListener('header-button-click', handler);
      }
    }
  });

  return <lit-web-component ref={ref} text="my text"></lit-web-component>;
}
```

A [future version of React (likely 19)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11347#issuecomment-1899140345) will add better custom element support so that you can add event listeners by prepending `on` to the event name and using that as a prop.

If you still wish to use the `@lit/react` wrapper,

based on the error, it seems like `createComponent` is inferring the type of the provided `elementClass` to be `HTMLElement`, when it should be the class extending `HTMLElement`, `LitWebComponent` which should also have the `text` property.

`@lit/react` exports a [`ReactWebComponent`](https://github.com/lit/lit/blob/2f5f73f03419bd0ecea21b05d3b126fd68931462/packages/react/src/create-component.ts#L46) type which you could try and use it like

```
import {createComponent, type ReactWebComponent} from '@lit/react';

const _MyElementComponent = createComponent({
  tagName: 'lit-web-component',
  elementClass: LitWebComponent,
  react: React,
  events: {
    onHeaderButtonClick: 'header-button-click',
  },
});

export const MyElementComponent =
  _MyElementComponent as ReactWebComponent<
    LitWebComponent, {onHeaderButtonClick: 'header-button-click'}
  >;
```

though if the type inference didn't work, I'm not sure that would work.

You can also assert the type more directly like

```
interface ElementProps {
  text: string;
  onHeaderButtonClick: (e: Event) => void;
}

export const MyElementComponent =
  _MyElementComponent as React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    React.PropsWithoutRef<ElementProps> & React.RefAttributes<LitWebComponent>
  >
```